# CSS - Responsive Image Size

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsiveness

I am trying to make all images have `max-width: 400px;` and at the same time be responsive i.e. mobile friendly.

The following styling did make the images responsive, but `max-width: 100%;` is making the images vary in size a lot more than wanted thus this is not a suitable solution.

```
max-width: 100%;
Width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px #DFDFDF solid; /* Just to make the image look nicer */
```

What I need is something along these lines (but responsive):

```
max-width: 400px;
width: auto;
height: auto;
border: 1px #DFDFDF solid; /* Just to make the image look nicer */
```

I've tried many different things, but I just can't get it to work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your images want to be the width of the parent, but you want to cap that width to not go above 400px.

```
max-width: 400px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
border: 1px #DFDFDF solid; /* Just to make the image look nicer */
```

To be a bit more in depth and have more control, you could split this out and use a media query to target your mobile display:

```
// Desktop
.your-img {
    max-width:400px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}

// Mobile
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .your-img {
        width:auto;     // Get the original width of the image
        max-width:100%; // So the image can only be as wide as the device max
        display:block;  // Image becomes a block element
        margin:0 auto;  // Centre image if smaller than device width
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: No problem, when dealign with responsive images on mobiles, I tend to either make them appear full width, or if you have an image that is naturally smaller than the device width, just set the image to be centred using `margin:0 auto;`